# excel export for richfaces:dataTable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to implement excel export for my  which is resulting an error
Following is the way I've tried

```
            <h:form id="excelExport"> 
        <a4j:outputPanel id="matched">            
            <h:panelGrid  width="100%" border="1">
                <rich:dataTable id="tblMatched" value="#{SampleBean.exportDataList}" var="iList" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="3" rows="10" width="100%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" >
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style="" value="Feed Id" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{iList.feedId}" > </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText style="" value="Data Source Name" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{iList.sourceName}" > </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
                <h:commandLink value="Export table" action="#{org.jboss.seam.excel.excelExporter.export('excelExport:tblMatched')}" />                    
            </h:panelGrid>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
```

when I click on the link I'm getting the following error

> SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /SampleExport.xhtml @76,139 action="#{org.jboss.seam.excel.excelExporter.export('excelExport:tblMatched')}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'org' resolved to null
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /SampleExport.xhtml @76,139 action="#{org.jboss.seam.excel.excelExporter.export('excelExport:tblMatched')}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'org' resolved to null

I've used jboss-seam-excel.jar and jxl.jar

Any suggestions to solve my problem...????

Comment: this is the way I added   <context-param>
<param-name>org.jboss.seam.excel.excelExporter</param-name>
  <param-value>ALL</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: check this out http://seamframework.org/49289.lace

Comment: I tried that...but did not help me...can you tell me if I can add prime faces for this..???primefaces has a <p:dataExporter>...my application has richfaces 3.x

Comment: data Exporter from dataTable ? Yes Primefaces has that. [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf)

Comment: it is there but...can i add both primefaces and richfaces in the application..or does it has any compatibility issues????

Comment: I dont have any experience of using both of them, I would again suggest to go step by step as mentioned in the link to resolve this issue.